# Generating relative requires in ClojureScript

Tags: node.js, clojurescript

I'm compiling a project to run on nodejs and ClojureScript, in the main file, generates these two lines:

```
require(path.join(path.resolve("."),"shell","goog","bootstrap","nodejs.js"));
require(path.join(path.resolve("."),"shell","cljs_deps.js"));
```

How can I instead generate:

```
require("./shell/goog/bootstrap/nodejs.js");
require("./shell/cljs_deps.js");
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it.
At least you can not make ClojureScript to generate any other code via configuration.

The reason is, it is hardcoded into CLJS compiler, as you can [see here](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/cdaeff298e0f1d410aa5a7b6860232270d287084/src/main/clojure/cljs/closure.clj#L1405).

On the other hand, you could file a pull request or open a ticket.